# How to avoid 'Uncaught ReferenceError: ? is undefined'?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, indexof

I have a script (config.js) at the base of every page. But, that script contains code that isn't used on every page. The console returns unused or undeclared variables as undefined.

```
let currentURL = document.location.href;

function redirectURL() {
  if (currentURL.indexOf('dogs.html') > -1) {
    redirect.innerHTML = `<a href="/pets/cats.html">Cats</a>`;
  } else {
    redirect.innerHTML = `<a href="/pets/dogs.html">Dogs</a>`;
  }
}
redirectURL();
```

This is what's returned.
[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: *What* is `undefined`? Which line has this error?

Comment: I updated the OP. `redirect is undefined` is what's returned.

Comment: I'm guessing "/pets/cats.html" should be "./pets/cats.html", and the same for the other link.

Comment: Your code does not declare or initialize a `redirect` variable, so it's `undefined`.

Comment: You need to do something like `let redirect = document.querySelector(".redirect-box")` Where .redirect-box is the object that you will be editing its innerhtml.

Comment: @imvain2 The function is used on multiple pages, and I presume some of them define `redirect` (perhaps taking advantage of IDs automatically becoming global variables), while others don't.

Comment: Because this is a pretty simple error to figure out. The error message is telling you exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check whether the `redirect` element exists before trying to use it.

```
function redirectURL() {
  if (typeof redirect == 'undefined') {
    return;
  }
  if (currentURL.indexOf('dogs.html') > -1) {
    redirect.innerHTML = `<a href="/pets/cats.html">Cats</a>`;
  } else {
    redirect.innerHTML = `<a href="/pets/dogs.html">Dogs</a>`;
  }
}
```

This will allow the function to work without error on pages that don't define `redirect`.

Comment: `if (!redirect)` still results in ReferenceError when `redirect` doesn't exist. `typeof redirect` would be safe from it.